# An inequality with operator norm

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, inequality

Let $T:X\to X$ be a bounded sublinear operator. How can we show that the following inequality is true:

$$
T^{k+1}f(x) \le 2 \|T\|\, T^{k}f(x), 
$$
where $\|T\|$ denotes the operator norm and $T^{k}=T\circ T\circ \dots\circ T$ is is $k$ iterations of the operator $T$.

My attempt is:

$$
\|T^{k+1}f\|\le \|T\|\|T^{k}f\|
$$
since $T$ is a bounded operator. But i can not continue.

Comment: Is this supposed to be true for all $f(x)$? Because if it's true for $f(x)$, it's false for $-f(x)$.

Comment: What kind of space is X?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong or your statement might not be completed.

Example:
$T f := (-1)\, f $ for $X = L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}).$

Consider any positive function $f_0,$ for instance $f_0(x) \equiv 1.$

$$T^k f_0 = (-1)^k 
\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\, \|T\|=1.$$
When $k$ is odd, your claim is false.